# How do we count "gales"

Tags: countable-nouns

I'm wondering how we can actually count "gales". When do we use the singular form and when do we use the plural form?

Here're two examples I've found:

Hundreds of old trees were blown down in the gales. (Cambridge Dictionary)

The gale blew down hundreds of trees. (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)

Thank you.

Comment: If a lot of wind blows, and then it stops, and tomorrow a lot of wind blows, that's at least two gales, isn't it?

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Plural means more than one. When a thing is two or more, use plural. A thing can cause damage, and so can things.

Answer (score 1):

> Hundreds of old trees were blown down in the gales. (Cambridge Dictionary)

The gales =  a series of separate gales within a given period. The gales = the period in which we had a number of gales.

> The gale blew down hundreds of trees. (Oxford Learner's Dictionaries)

This is the basic use of "gale": it refers to one gale of which the listener is aware.

Comment: I'd say it's more notional than precisionist, and that there is a register ('gales' being perhaps more poetic) factor too. 'In the gales' can conjure up to my mind a single period with fluctuations in wind intensity, sometimes reaching the 'gale' threshold. Of course, there may well be a series of such episodes over a longer timespan.

Comment: "That good ship and true was a bone to be chewed
When the gales of November came early" Gordon Lightfoot.